# Why are MySQL system user passwords incorrect?

Tags: mysql

I was adding a user to my server via MySQL Workbench. Something went awry; the addition failed. Afterwards my root account could no longer access the DB via Workbench. (access denied)
I was able to connect as root from the command line mysql -uroot -p but root has no privileges.
This system has been in place and working, until now, for over a year

The log shows:
`Found invalid password for user: 'mysql.infoschema@localhost'; Ignoring user`
`Found invalid password for user: 'mysql.session@localhost'; Ignoring user`
`Found invalid password for user: 'mysql.sys@localhost'; Ignoring user`

I have no user with GRANT privileges.
How can I correct the invalid Password issue for these system users?

MySQL 8
Centos 7

Comment: Those three accounts have invalid passwords by default https://www.thegeekdiary.com/what-are-reserved-user-accounts-in-mysql/

Comment: This post explains how to restore GRANT privileges to `root` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges

Answer (score 2):

Those have intentional invalid passwords.

If you still have access issues it might be a good idea to verify that you don't have any memory corruption or disk corruption.

If you fail to get access you can in the absolute worst case you could [start mysql in insecure mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization.html), which let's you do whatever you want. (or rather will anyone do so, so disable network access first)

## make backups, and be careful!